# The report with several columns: How to reprint group headers in each column?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm creating a report with 2 columns per page with *JasperReports 4.7.1*.

When the records belonging to a group span across multiple columns, I want to print the header not only at the beginning of the group but also at the start of each column.

Using ***Reprint Header*** (***isReprintHeaderOnEachPage*** property) in group properties, header can be printed at the start of each page. But I still couldn't find a way to do the same at the start of a new column.

How can I achieve this?

Screenshot of the current report page...

[image]

What I want to achieve (note the headers in the 2nd column)...

[image]

Comment: Do you want to break the data belonging to the single group and printed in *Detail* band with information from *Group Header*? Can you post the pictures (screenshots) to illustrate your current and target design?

Comment: I'm unable to post any screenshots of it. If I try to explain, the _Group Header_ contains the labels which should be printed as headers of a table displayed. When the group changes, a new table is printed. Records of the table are displayed in the _Detail_ band. This table may span to 2 _report columns_. In the 1st report column, headers are printed because that's where the group starts. What I want to do is to print them at the start of the 2nd column also. Thanks

Comment: @AlexK I have attached the screenshots. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Finally I've got your question :) You can try to customize the ***net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRHorizontalFiller*** class. Look at ***fillGroupHeaderReprint(JRFillGroup, byte)*** method – Alex K 14 mins ago

Comment: @AlexK I've managed to come up with a workaround. I created a report _Variable_ to count the records in the column. Then use it in the _print when_ expression of header elements. Count == 1 means we are at the top of the column. It is not a proper solution (and it is tedious) because all the header elements should include this _print when_ condition. I'm still testing it. If that doesn't work properly patching the class seems to be the only solution left. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to yours and I managed to solve it by adding a ColumnHeader band and only displaying it for the 2nd column of my 2-column report.

It is important to have isReprintHeaderOnEachPage set to true and the height of the groupHeader and columnHeader to be the same for my solution to work.

Here is the relevant code (of course you replace "telephoneNumber" with your appropriate group expression:

```
<group name="telephoneNumberGroup" isStartNewPage="true" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{telephoneNumber}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="17">
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="5" y="0" width="170" height="15" uuid="5e8b892b-f907-4907-9c6d-4419e57325e5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="6" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{telephoneNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="17">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{COLUMN_NUMBER} == 2]]></printWhenExpression>
        <textField>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="5" y="0" width="170" height="15" uuid="5e8b892b-f907-4907-9c6d-4419e57325e5"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="6" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{telephoneNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
```